# How can I repair a large myisam database when diskspace is low?

Tags: mariadb, myisam, disk-space

MariaDB 10 | CentOS 5.x

I have a large myisam database with some tables that are marked as crashed.  The collective size in `/var/lib/mysql/fooDatabase/` is 17 GB.  I have 4 GB of space left.

Initially, I tried running `mysqlcheck --verbose --auto-repair fooDatabase` but that failed and in logs I see:

```
[Warning] mysqld: Disk is full writing '.fooDatabase/foo_TABLE.TMD' (Errcode:28 "No space left on device"_. Waiting for someone to free space...)
```

I restarted mariadb and reclaimed the disk space but I'm back to square one here.

I'm now running `repair table foo_TABLE;` but I'm not sure if I'll experience the same problem or not.

At this point, I've squeezed as much free disk space out of the system as I can.  Are there any other options?  Are there any repair operations that are more sparing with temporary disk space?  Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have many options here.

Since you're running MyISAM storage engine, you may try to snapshot your files, e.g. with `mysqlhotcopy`, repair the snapshot on another host with much more space, then copy the repaired data files back to the original host.